# Can I prevent myself from sending mail to a similarly named colleague?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I have an email address that is different from another person in my company by one letter in my last name, let's call him Joss. Sometimes I receive emails meant for Joss, and it is almost always from the same sender (lets call him, "Bob") . I have set up an outlook rule for these specific conditions which responds (only to Bob) with a canned message along the lines of, "Did you mean joss@company" and also forwards the email to Joss.

Now, responding after the email is received is great and was easy to set up, but if the message sparks a conversation, then Joss is missing out.

Is there a way in Outlook for Bob to prevent sending to my email address, or at least confirm he does in fact mean to send the message to me and not Joss?

I know I cant implement this on his machine, but if I can send Bob info on how to do it himself that might help.

Comment: It might be easier to change your e-mail addresses to something more distinct, for instance, by adding your surnames.

Comment: From Bob's Outlook profile, create a new email and in the **To** field make your email address auto-populate by typing in the first few characters and then press the "X" to delete that auto-populated and saved entry. Now setup a new contact on Bob's Outlook profile with your email address, etc. and be sure the **Full Name** and/or the **Display As** are different and clearly distinct from Joss' for however that looks. Now he should be able to easily distinguish between the two. Let me know if this helps and if you'd like me to add an answer with more detail, etc.